# PHPStorm - xDebugg - variables listing

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

When going though my code with the debugg, you are able to see the variable and their values etc etc.

However, if an array has 200 odd variables or if an object has 300+ defs for it. It takes ages to find it straight away (once i find the variable i need, i put it under my watch list)

My questions is: How can you list the variable in alphabetical order or in any order at all within the debug variables list?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Comment: If an object has 300 properties, you probably need to consider refactoring it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Debug tool window has an option to **sort variables/array keys alphabetically**. For that -- activate that option via "cog" icon:
   [image]

   NOTE: you can add that option as separate button on debug toolbar (look for A-Z icon on screenshot above) if you need to turn this option ON or OFF often. This can be done via `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Menus and Toolbars`.
2. **Standard in place search** works there (in variables panel) as well. For that just start typing while panel has focus.

   NOTE that search looks trough already expanded nodes only (just like in other places) -- it will NOT open nodes for you (e.g. if you are trying to find variable/key that is located in closed node then it will not be found).

Comment: Great thanks for that LazyOne! Just saved me about an hour a day at work!...probably XD